# Fizzbuzz function logic not working: Output order is incorrect and logic doesn't make sense

Tags: javascript, arrays, fizzbuzz

I'm creating a simple [Javascript Function](https://codepen.io/solange_io/pen/eYjZPOj) that should write the numbers from 1 to n. For any multiplier of 3, it outputs "Fizz", instead of multiplers of 5 you output "Buzz", and if they happen at the same time, you should use "FizzBuzz". The output of the function should be a mixed array of numbers and strings.

My current code is outputting the array order and expected values incorrectly.

```
function fizzbuzz (n) {
  let arr = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
      //if i is a multiple of 3 then Fizz
      if(i % 3 === 0) {
        arr.push("Fizz");
      }
      //if i is a multiple of 5 then Buz
      if(i % 5 == 0) {
        arr.push("Buzz");
      }
      //if both then FizzBuzz
      if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        arr.push("FizzBuzz");
      }
      else {
        arr.push(i);
      }
    }
  return arr;
}
```

When `fizzbuzz(7)` is entered, I expect the output to look like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, "Fizz", 4, "Buzz", "Fizz", 7];
```

Instead, it's this:

```
["Fizz","Buzz","FizzBuzz",1,2,"Fizz",3,4,"Buzz",5,"Fizz",6]
```

Could someone enlighten me to the fault in my logic? This should be more straightforward than I had originally thought.

Comment: You should use else if instead of just ifs following each other because if it's both a multiplier of 3 and 5, all 3 first conditions are true and are gonna be executed

Answer (score 2):

You have three different `if` statements there, the last one having an `else` clause, instead of one continuous `if` statement with several `else if` clauses. Note that for this to work properly you need to **first** test the "FizzBuzz" condition:

```js
function fizzbuzz (n) {
  let arr = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
      //if both then FizzBuzz
      if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        arr.push("FizzBuzz");
      }
      //if i is a multiple of 3 then Fizz
      else if(i % 3 === 0) { // Changed to an else-if
        arr.push("Fizz");
      }
      //if i is a multiple of 5 then Buz
      else if(i % 5 == 0) { // Changed to an else-if
        arr.push("Buzz");
      }
      else {
        arr.push(i);
      }
    }
  return arr;
}
```

Quick note regarding the expected output - 0 is divisible by 3 and 5 (and other other integer, for that matter), so the first element of the array should be "FizzBuzz"

Comment: And also for the output to be exactly the same the condition < in the for loop should be <=